# Align inline-block items with left and right edge of container

Tags: html, css

This is a bit tricky to explain what I'm trying to do, but I'll try my best.

- I have X number of categories.
- I want to put each category in a box with a grey border.
- I want to display the category boxes as "inline-block", left to right.
- There could be 1,2,3,4,5.... ACROSS the page depending on the users screen size.
- I want the boxes that are positioned on the left to be right up against the left hand side of the container.
  I want the boxes that are position on the right to be right up against the right hand side of the container.

Like so:

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
}

.category {
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="category">Category 1</div>
  <div class="category">Category 2</div>
  <div class="category">Category 3</div>
  <div class="category">Category 4</div>
  <div class="category">Category 5</div>
  <div class="category">Category 6</div>
</div>
```

If I was to change:

```
.container {
  column-count:4; 
}
```

This achieves the effect I am looking for.
BUT - they are no longer in order across the screen. The categories are displayed top -> bottom rather than left->right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flexbox to the rescue. In the following example, the elements are fixed width and the space between them is distributed evenly:

```css
.container {
  margin: 1em 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.category {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="category">Category 1</div>
  <div class="category">Category 2</div>
  <div class="category">Category 3</div>
  <div class="category">Category 4</div>
  <div class="category">Category 5</div>
  <div class="category">Category 6</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="category">Category 1</div>
  <div class="category">Category 2</div>
  <div class="category">Category 3</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="category">Category 1</div>
  <div class="category">Category 2</div>
</div>
```

In the following example, the elements are fluid width and the space between them is fixed:

```css
.container {
  margin: 1em 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.category {
  margin: 0 1em;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  width: calc(25% - 2em - 2px);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="category">Category 1</div>
  <div class="category">Category 2</div>
  <div class="category">Category 3</div>
  <div class="category">Category 4</div>
  <div class="category">Category 5</div>
  <div class="category">Category 6</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="category">Category 1</div>
  <div class="category">Category 2</div>
  <div class="category">Category 3</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="category">Category 1</div>
  <div class="category">Category 2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've just noticed one more thing. This is 90% of the way there :-) If there were only 2 items (for example) in my list, but the screen could take 3 or 4 elements, this leaves a big space in-between the two elements. Any ideas? See example here: http://beta.bearingboys.co.uk/Rod-End-Bearings-3635-c

Comment: You need to allow the items to stretch, different rules. I'll update the answer shortly.